# Enable/disable textarea after taking input from keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a textarea which is disabled by default. And then on press of 'Edit' I take some input from user. If it is valid, I want to enable the textarea. Here is the code which I have right now:

```
<textarea name="comment" cols="5" rows="2" disabled="true"><%= $tmp_com %></textarea>
<a href="javascript:validateUser()">Edit</a>

function validateUser(){
var name=prompt("Please enter the password");

    if (name=="1234")
    {
       document.getElementByName("comment").disabled="false";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its better for you to use id instead of name. Any way I'm using name here to follow the question.

```
<a href="javascript:validateUser()">Edit</a>
<textarea name="comment" cols="5" rows="2" disabled="disabled">aaaaa</textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateUser(){
        var name=prompt("Please enter the password");
        if (name=="1234")
        document.getElementsByName("comment")[0].disabled=false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ...And a string for the value "false" - Better to use true/false without strings as these are numbers really.

Answer (score 12):

There is no getElementByName in JavaScript. Easiest solution, add an id, and use getElementById.

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="5" rows="2" disabled="true">
```

and JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("comment").disabled="false";
```

Comment: Almost. Remove the quotes around "false" to make the argument a boolean and not a string, and you'll have it.

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery

```
$("[name='comment']").attr('disabled', true);
$("[name='comment']").attr('disabled', false);
```

or by Id

```
$("#comment").attr('disabled', true);
```